# When we write, do we have to write "OK" instead of "Ok" or are both correct?

Tags: writing, orthography

I'm confused when I have to write "Ok" in a writing, because I don't know if "OK" and "Ok" are both orthographically correct or just one is.

Comment: I would think to be pedantically correct you would either write 'OK', the abbreviation for okay (or for the US state Oklahoma), or the full word 'okay'. However, OK is informal, and I think it's fairly common to write it either way (OK or ok). I wouldn't write Ok unless it was the start of a sentence.

Comment: In English it's Okay or OK (sometimes O.K.). In Italian it is a loan word from English and is written *Ok*. That's fine if they are writing in Italian. But  when they write in English, I ask native Italian speakers and other non-native speakers of English to correct it to *Okay* or *OK* because I assume they want to write the way English speakers do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[OK](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ok) is the abbreviation for *oll korrect* or *orl korrect* representing all correct. There are numerous explanations for the origin of the expression as suggested by the linked [Wikipedia article](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/90597/when-we-write-do-we-have-to-write-ok-instead-of-ok-or-are-both-correct/90602#90602).

You don't write *Usa* or *USa* for *USA* because *USA* is the abbreviation for *the United States of America*.

However, there are many forms of [abbreviations](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/abbreviations.htm) in English and there is no hard-and-fast rule. For example, you abbreviate *mister* to *Mr.* or *Mr* and *Doctor of Philosophy* to *PhD*.

You could write *Ok* or *ok* in a text message or informal writing, but you should use one of the following three in formal writing. I would prefer *OK* to *O.K.*.

> OK
>
> okay
>
> O.K.

Comment: +1 because I am constantly telling learners that in English it is  *OK* or *Okay* and not *Ok*. However, there is some first language interference, for in Italian the norm is *Ok*, which is "Okay by me," since Italian speakers can decide how they want to write it–in Italian. A side issue is that  *Mister* is  shortened to *Mr* in [British English](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/is-it-proper-to-omit-periods-after-honorifics-mr-mrs-dr).

Comment: "Okay" is the expansion of OK, not the other way around. OK is an abbreviation of "oll korrect," not "okay." "Okay" came later.

Comment: @anaranjada: That's not right. The word (in whatever spelling you like) was originally borrowed from Choctaw. The "oll korrect" joke-interpretation came later. (See https://web.archive.org/web/20120208134453/http://www.illinoisprairie.info/chocokeh.htm; hat-tip to http://english.stackexchange.com/a/60686/14775.) Unfortunately, the mistake has made it into some highly-regarded dictionaries.

Comment: @ruakh: The etymology seems unclear, considering other answers on that page. Rathony, I think it might be better to say something like "OK may have originated as an abbreviation of *oll correct*" to reflect this uncertainty.

Comment: @ruakh Interesting, but the OED doesn't think so. The 1828 and 1841 editions of Noah Webster's dictionary don't even list "OK" or "okay." Neither did Joseph Worcester's 1830 dictionary. I'm running low on 19th-century dictionaries to check.

Comment: @anaranjada: Just read the page I linked to. :-)    (The OED is one of the "highly-regarded dictionaries" I referred to. Even Homer nods.)

Comment: @ruakh I don't think the etymology is all that clear. There seems to be a lack of documentation supporting most theories, as OED mentions. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=OK http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?EtymologyOfOkay

Comment: Whatever happened to words like 'fine', 'right', 'excellent', 'all right','agreed', and so many other fine words. Nowadays, everyone says that ugly OK/Ok/ok which is not really all that OK/Ok/ok.

Answer (score 5):

The important thing to understand is:

**OK** is written as if it were an an acronym even though it doesn't stand for anything but itself.

So, the common practice in print is to write **OK** or **O.K.** or **okay** but not **Ok**.

There are various hypotheses about the origin of OK, like "oll korrect" (a joke misspelling for "all correct") or "Old Kinderhook" (a nickname of Martin Van Buren), but few people have heard of those things, and really, nobody knows. The origin of OK doesn't matter, because when people use the word today, they are not invoking an ongoing tradition in which the letters stand for something other than the spoken word "okay".

Some people say that OK stands for "okay" in the same way that IOU (as a noun, as in "I'll give you an IOU for $6") stands for the phrase "I owe you". As a theory of the origin of OK, that's probably wrong. But it correctly explains how the word OK communicates today and why it's customary to write it with two capital letters. When people write "IOU", they expect the reader to understand that the letters stand for "I owe you" because the names of the letters sound the same as the words. When people write "OK", they do not expect the reader to understand that the letters stand for "oll korrect". They do expect the reader to understand it as meaning "okay", which is pronounced the same as the letters "OK".